# Tag user on fan page photo

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tags, photos, facebook-page

Using GRAPH API, how can I tag myself on a fanpage photo (page that allows anyone to tag)?

Docs says you only need:

- Publish_stream permission
- POST to /photo_id/tags/my_user_id

I tried it but facebook responds with an 500: Oauth Exception, An unknown error has occurred.

Tagging myself or friend in user photos works OK, but tagging on pages photos causes the error.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Related bug, filled by me:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/261936030593730

Comment: This is a known bug, there are other bugs tracking progress of this issue. Please subscribe to them for updates - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/147932672009060

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the page has the option

```
Tagging Ability: [X] People can tag photos posted by {page}
```

set in it’s settings under *Manage Permissions* …?

Comment: Yep, page has this option. I can tag myself via Facebook Website. The problem is with Graph API. You can check at www.fb.com/sharespot

Answer (score 0):

When you publish photo through fan page and wanted to tag friends in it, you need page access_token instead of user access_token. You are using user's access_token so the error

> 500: Oauth Exception, An unknown error has occurred.

Quoting fb docs from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens)

> To perform the following operations as a Page, and not the current
>   user, you must use the Page's access token, not the user access token
>   commonly used for reading Graph API objects. This access token can be
>   retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts with the
>   manage_pages permission. This will return a list of Pages (including
>   application profile Pages) to which the user has administrative
>   access, along with access_tokens for those Pages. Alternatively, you
>   can get a page access token for a single, specific, page by issuing an
>   HTTP GET to /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the manage_pages
>   permission, as described above. Publishing to a Page also requires the
>   publish_stream permission, unless otherwise noted.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to tag myself in the page photo. Like I would do if I saw a pic of mine on a fanpage. I'm not trying to, as a page, tag someone.